# BSOD 0xA0 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, minidumps, windbg

I have some problems with a bluescreen on a Windows XP SP3.
The Bugcheck code is 0x000000A0 and the first parameter 0x00000101 states that there is a

> Unhandled exception occured while processing a system power event

I tried to find out what's the problem but I'm not really good in using windbg yet. I've uploaded the minidump for you to have a look at it: http://www.file-upload.net/download-4692991/Mini082012-01.zip.html

How do I fix this error?

Edit: after executing `!analyze -v` windbg shows me this line: `DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT`. What is a "DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID"? Is a driver causing this error?

Comment: I would replace the power supply.

Comment: for what reason? It wouldn't solve the problem if there's a driver which isn't able to process power events properly.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error point out highly "power supply" problem. If you provide more details related to when the problem occurs(which program running what are you doing etc) this can speed up diagnosis process.

But if this problem occurs when your PC attempt to hibernate or sleep, then your problem is because the size of the hibernation file (hiberfil.sys) size is not large or big enough to save and store current contents loading in the system RAM or memory.

You can easily fix this;

1-Open a command prompt window with elevated administrator privileges.
2-Type the following command and press ENTER:

```
powercfg /hibernate /size 100
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: I asked the user of that pc (it's not mine) and he said that the BSOD only occurs on startup. It's not configured to go to sleep after an amount of time.

Comment: and btw: your suggested powercfg command didn't work. is it probably for later versions of windows than xp?